# Only Chrome shows different html file

Tags: javascript, html

This is a very strange bug I encountered..

When I load my React website on other browsers(Edge, Firefox, even mobile Chrome) it displays the webpage correctly. But only on Chrome, nothing is displayed. I eventually discovered that this is because Chrome tries to load a different js file - the  tag contained /static/js/main.ce5cbd14.js instead of /static/js/main.08ed2491.js, so the js file was not found.

I thought I was sending a different html file from the server and tried logging the file contents, but instead found that such file does not exist and that the file displayed by other browsers were indeed the one being sent to Chrome as well. So the only thing I can imagine is that Chrome for some reason replaced the src link with another one. What could potentially cause this? Does Chrome save past html files as cache in certain cases?

(And yes, I turned off all the add-ons as well)

Comment: did you clear the browser cache? try clearing the cache and then ctrl+f5 to load the site

Comment: Maybe you need to clear cache or stored cookies.
I often find that the pages I create sometimes don't turn out as they should due to cache issues. As a usual solution, do the following: clear cache & cookies, use incognito, use another browser.

~maybe it can help.

Comment: This.. actually solved it. Thank you so much. But Chrome was clearly loading a file from the server, that's for certain. So does Chrome sometimes load a file, but still ignore that and use the cache anyway?

Comment: In my experience, Chrome sometimes has issues giving up cached pages

Answer (score 1):

I see you solved your issue with caching on Google Chrome Browser.

For posterity sake, I wanted to add some info on Chromium caching policy especially info related to [cache address](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/disk-cache/#cache-address). Considering that [many browsers now base their engine on the Chromium engine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)#Browsers_based_on_Chromium), it will help future readers understand how their browser’s caching policy works (no matter how little the knowledge gained).

[See disk caching in Chromium browsers.](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/disk-cache/#overview)